# Convolve[...] behaves differently to that of Integrate[...] when numerically integrating the result

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, convolution

I am performing a convolution between two functions, and then I want to numerically integrate the result.

If I go:

```
Result1[y_] = Integrate[F[x - y] * G[y],{y,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

I can then easily numerically integrate the result to whatever integration limit I want as;

```
NIntegrate[Result1[y],{y,-Infinity,UpplerLimit}]
```

And I get a result which is consistent. However If I now use the Mathematica function `Convolve[...]` Which I want to use for programmatic reasons, as,

```
Result1[y_] = Convolve[F[x],G[x],x,y]
```

this also returns nicely and if I plot `Result1[y]` and `Result2[y]` they are identical, BUT, if I then numerically integrated `Result2[y]` (produced with Mathematica's `Convolve[...]`) I get the error:

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

And

```
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {-1.30639}. NIntegrate obtained -1.90282 and 0.8427893482198415` for the integral and error estimates.
```

Can anyone explain this?